# Python import modules issue

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I recently was asked to deliver a python project as part of an interview process.
I tested my project on Windows and MacOSX, with Pycharm, Spyder, jupyter notebook and command line and everything works fine.

However, the reviewer was unable to make the project work on his side, because of module import issues according to him.

My modules are organized like this:

```
my_project/
  my_module.py
  main_module.py
  my_package/
    __init__.py
    my_submodule_1.py
    my_submodule_2.py
```

my_submodule_1.py:

```
import my_module
import my_submodule_2
```

I haven't added any path related to this project in PYTHONPATH.
The project main function is located in `main_module.py`.
The reviewer seem to have problems with the modules imported in `my_submodule_1.py.`

Could anyone shed some light on possible mistakes here and why it would work on my side and not on his?

Comment: There are two things I can see. 
1- If you are importing my_module (which is parent directory) in subdirectory file, then you may have to run the python file from the parent directory. **python my_package/my_submodule_1.py** to run and **from my_package import my_submodule_1** if you are importing in a file.

Comment: 2- And second thing is if you are running it from parent directory then, submodule file should have imports something like this **from my_package import my_submodule_2** to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `my_submodule_1` module is doing an implicit relative import when it imports `my_submodule_2` directly.

That's not legal in Python 3. It *is* allowed in Python 2, though its usually a bad idea to use it.  You can get the Python 3 semantics by putting `from __future__ import absolute_import` above the other import statements in your file. To fix the import, you'd want to change `import my_submodule_2` to either `import my_package.my_submodule_2` (an absolute import) or `from . import my_submodule2` (an explicit relative import).

If your interviewer is using Python 3 and you're using Python 2, there are likely to be other issues with your code (especially if you're doing any sort of text processing), so I'd make sure you're testing your code in the version they expect!

Comment: it seems that is the issue, I switched from 2.7 to 3.5 and indeed I have import issues

Answer (score 0):

I think since **my_module.py** is not in **same directory** as **my_submodule1.py** ,and on the reviewer pc the **sys.path** doesn't have that location of **my_module.py**, that's why it getting problem in importing the module from its parent directory.

if u give the details of error that the reviewer is getting it might help finding the right solution.